# How to migrate from camel-restlet to camel-http - EndpointSetup

Tags: apache-camel, camel-http

I want to migrate a Camel 2 application to a camel 3 application. For me the most important part is about the removal of camel-restlet? Is there any guide?

My current problem is the endpoint setup. My restlet endpoint is configured this way (I try to minimize the use of string literals):

```
private Endpoint getRestEndpoint(String path) {
    RestletEndpoint endpoint = context.getEndpoint("restlet:" + path, RestletEndpoint.class);
    endpoint.setRestletMethod(Method.GET);
    endpoint.setHost("0.0.0.0");
    endpoint.setProtocol("http");
    endpoint.setPort(port);
    endpoint.setRestletRealm(users);
    return endpoint;
}
```

I guess I need to substitute RestletEndpoint by `HttpCommonEndpoint`? and "restlet" becomes "http"?

But from here all methods changed. While I found substitute for for method I didn't find any substitutes for the others. So how to get a equivalent http endpoint?